# phpseclib connect to localhost using sftp - ssh

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I'm working with phpseclib (https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) and I come across a problem that I don't know how to solve.

So basically I would like to use PHP to connect to the same server that the script is running on via SSH to perform some SFTP transaction.

I tried `ssh localhost` on command line and it logs me in using my SSH key-pair.

I implemented phpseclib to download/upload files from/to a remote server. Now I am writing unit tests for the code I've written. However, I cannot mock SFTP class since the object needs to be initiated for every connection, is there a way to test the function that I've written, basically just a file download and process data function.

Comment: phpseclib is unit tested. SSH2 is unit tested by having Travis CI install an SSH server on the testing VM. You can see how phpseclib sets it up at https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/travis/setup-secure-shell.sh idk if that helps

Answer (score 0):

My guess: your `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file is the private key corresponding to the public key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. So when you try to login with `ssh localhost` it isn't actually logging you without authentication - it's logging you in with a public key but you just don't realize it.

A few other less likely possibilities:

1. You have ssh-agent installed and are using that without realizing it.
2. You're authentication with host-based authentication (which phpseclib doesn't support)

Doing `ssh -v localhost` and then posting what it says might be helpful.

Comment: you are right, I'm using SSH key-pair to access my server. and the verbose log shows it. I have updated my question